# Tastypie - sort nested array

Tags: django-models, tastypie, django-orm

I am calling data that includes a nested array.

Example:

```
data = [
    'name':'John', 'likes': ['Women', 'Bars', 'Women_In_Bars', 'turtles'],
    'name': 'Steve', 'likes': ['Men', 'Clubs', 'Men_In_Clubs', 'cats']
    ]
```

I am already sorting by `name` in my queryset, and the Resource is already mapped correctly to the other `likeResource` as per [the docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html).

**How can I also return the nested `likes` in a sorted order?**

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to say if you don't share the code where you are creating each resource, etc...

I guess you could try using the dehydrate function:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    #bundle.data['data'] might contain the array you mention above
    for item in bundle.data['data']:
        sort_function(item['likes'])
```

Hope it helps!